# Changing Shell Text Color (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, text, colors

I'm looking for a way to change the color of the text output from my python scripts as it runs.  The basic idea is something like this:

```
if (Data < LowerLimit):
    print "Failed" # Output Failed as Red Text
elif (Data > UpperLimit):
    print "Failed" # Red Color
else:
    print "Passed" # Blue Color
```

The scripts are being used on windows machines for quick data analysis.

Comment: a duplicate, although almost none of the solutions in the linked question work on windows.

Comment: Please see the answer here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599663/3057246

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Or about the best module I have found 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Comment: Yes - colorama actually works for the Windows 7 command prompt. Prior to windows 10, the ANSI codes don't work (for some inscrutable reason) in the command prompt. Colorama can use Win32 commands entirely transparantly - which makes it work and makes it easy to use. I'm glad I finally found a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Noiseinthestreet Can you this this => https://stackoverflow.com/a/70599663/3057246

Answer (score 16):

This is extremely simple! Rather than importing odd modules for python or trying long commands you can take advantage of windows OS commands.

In windows, commands exist to change the command prompt text color. You can use this in python by starting with a: `import os`

Next you need to have a line changing the text color, place it were you want in your code.
`os.system('color 4')`

You can figure out the other colors by starting cmd.exe and typing color help.

The good part? Thats all their is to it, to simple lines of code.
-Day

Comment: That changes the colour of the whole console, not just the text printed afterwards.

Comment: Sorry about that guys. I was sleepy and totally misunderstood the question.

Comment: It's still a valid answer to the EXTREMELY RELATED question LIKELY TO GET MARKED DUPLICATE which is how to change shell text color in Python...

Comment: Upvoted, because while it might not exactly answer the original question, this does answer my question for which Google brought me here.

Comment: Actually, if you run os.system('color'), then the ANSI escape sequences magically start working in windows.

Comment: See here to print colorful text on any console without any fancy modules (simple and easy) 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72752520/18522747

Comment: did not work. I think zvone might be right.