# Changing the font color of the command promt window when executing Python script

Tags: python, cmd, colors

In C++ I can type system("pause") or system("color A") to change things right inside the executing command prompt window.

---

Is it also possible with Python? I'd like to color my text of my script that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows Prompts you just have to `import os` and then add `os.system('color 1')` to your code.

You can find colors by starting cmd and executing `color help`.

If you are looking for something else I strongly suggest you to look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537487/changing-shell-text-color-windows), both are questions here in stackoverflow and are very similar to yours.