# Compile Python Program but output the colours as well?

Tags: python, colors, compiler-errors, pycharm, exe

I've made a very basic math practicing program in python for my kids and some other parents have asked about using it. The only issue is that when I try to compile it, it outputs in terminal and doesn't have any of the colours I added to it that work just fine for me in PyCharm. Is there a way to get the colours to run properly so it runs similar to the way it does for me in PyCharm if I share it with others? Complete code is below. I'm looking to make a simple .exe for people to download and share, since schools are closed down.

```
import os
import json
import random
import sys
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output


class bc:
    head = '\033[95m'
    blue = '\033[94m'
    green = '\033[92m'
    yellow = '\033[93m'
    red = '\033[91m'
    end = '\033[0m'
    bold = '\033[1m'
    under = '\033[4m'


def cl():
    clear_output()


pinfo = {}
pinfoall = []
seta = []
setb = []
setc = []
setd = []


def log():
    global pinfo
    global pinfoall
    login = input("Please Enter Your Player Name: ")
    if os.path.isfile("./mathdata.json") and os.stat("./mathdata.json").st_size != 0:
        datas = open("./mathdata.json", "r+")
        pinfoall = json.loads(datas.read())
        datas.close()
        pfound = False
        for item in pinfoall:
            if item["Player"] == login:
                cl()
                print(bc.blue + "\n Welcome Back to Math Masters, " + bc.green + login + bc.blue + "!" + bc.end)
                print(bc.end + "Type your answer to answer a question. To quit and save your progress type 'q'.")
                time.sleep(4)
                pinfo = item
                pfound = True
        if pfound:
            pinfoall.pop(pinfoall.index(pinfo))
        if not pfound:
            a = 0
            while a == 0:
                new = input("No player named " + login + " found. Create new player?  ('y' for yes, 'n' to retype login)")
                if new == "y":
                    pinfo = {"Player": login, "Level": 1, "XP": 0, "HP": 10, "HPMax": 10}
                    print(bc.blue + "\n Welcome to Math Masters, " + bc.green + login + bc.blue + "!" + bc.end)
                    print(bc.end + "Type your answer to answer a question. To quit and save your progress type 'q'.")
                    time.sleep(4)
                    a += 1
                elif new == "n":
                    log()
                    a += 1
                else:
                    print(bc.red + bc.bold + "Must type 'y' or 'n'!")
    else:
        pinfo = {"Player": login, "Level": 1, "XP": 0, "HP": 10, "HPMax": 10}
        print(bc.blue + "\n Welcome to Math Masters, " + bc.green + login + bc.blue + "!" + bc.end)
        print(bc.end + "Type your answer to answer a question. To quit and save your progress type 'q'.")
        time.sleep(6)
        pinfoall = []
        datas = open("./mathdata.json", "w+")
        datas.write(json.dumps(pinfoall))
        datas.close()


log()


class pl:
    name = pinfo["Player"]
    lv = pinfo["Level"]
    xp = pinfo["XP"]
    hp = pinfo["HP"]
    mhp = pinfo["HPMax"]


def nums_a_s(level):
    global seta
    global setb
    seta = []
    setb = []
    for i in range(0, 5+level):
        seta.insert(len(seta), i)
        setb.insert(len(setb), i)


def nums_m_s(level):
    global setc
    global setd
    setc = []
    setd = []
    if level > 14:
        setc = [0, 1, 2]
        setd = [0, 1, 2]
    if level > 17:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3]
    if level > 20:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    if level > 23:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    if level > 26:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    if level > 29:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    if level > 32:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    if level > 35:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    if level > 38:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    if level > 41:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
    if level > 44:
        setc = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
        setd = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]


def equation(level):
    if level < 15:
        ops = [0, 1]
    else:
        ops = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        num3 = random.choice(setc)
        num4 = random.choice(setd)
    op = random.choice(ops)
    num1 = random.choice(seta)
    num2 = random.choice(setb)
    if op == 0:
        eq = "What is "+  str(num1) + " + " + str(num2) + "?   " + " (Addition)\n"
        ans = str(num1 + num2)
    if op == 1:
        if level < 10:
            if num1 < num2:
                a = num1
                num1 = num2
                num2 = a
        eq = "What is " + str(num1) + " - " + str(num2) + "?   " + " (Subtraction)\n"
        ans = str(num1 - num2)
    if op == 2:
        eq = "What is " + str(num3) + " X " + str(num4) + "?   " + " (Multiplication)\n"
        ans = str(num1 * num2)
    if op == 3:
        a = -1
        b = -1
        while a not in setc:
            denom = random.choice(setd[1:])
            numer = random.choice(setc)
            if numer % denom == 0:
                a = numer
                b = denom
        eq = "What is " + str(a) + " ÷ " + str(b) + "?   " + " (Division)\n"
        ans = str(a/b)
    return eq, ans


def correct():
    print(bc.green + "CORRECT! " + bc.blue + "Good job, " + bc.green + pl.name + bc.blue + "!" + bc.end)
    if pl.xp < 9:
        pl.xp += 1
        print(bc.blue + "You gained " + bc.green + "1" + bc.blue + " experience point!" + bc.end)
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print(bc.blue + "You gained a" + bc.red + " LEVEL" + bc.blue + "! You are now level " +
              bc.green + str(pl.lv + 1) + bc.blue + "!\nYour Hit Points increased by " + bc.green + "5" + bc.blue +
              " and have been fully restored!" + bc.end)
        pl.lv += 1
        pl.mhp += 5
        pl.hp = pl.mhp
        pl.xp = 0
        time.sleep(5)
    os.remove("mathdata.json")
    pinfo["Level"] = pl.lv
    pinfo["HP"] = pl.hp
    pinfo["HPMax"] = pl.mhp
    pinfo["XP"] = pl.xp
    datas = open("mathdata.json", "w+")
    datas.write(json.dumps(pinfoall + [pinfo]))
    datas.close()


def wrong():
    pl.hp -= 5
    print(bc.red + "WRONG!" + bc.blue + " Better luck next question, " + bc.green + pl.name + bc.blue + "! You took " +
          bc.red + "5" + bc.blue + " Hit Points of damage." + bc.end)
    if pl.hp < 1:
        if pl.lv > 1:
            print(bc.blue + "You" + bc.red + " DIED" + bc.blue + "! You are now level " +
                  bc.green + str(pl.lv - 1) + bc.blue + "!\nYour Max Hit Points decreased by " + bc.green + "5" + bc.blue +
                  "." + bc.end)
            pl.lv -= 1
            pl.mhp -= 5
            pl.hp = pl.mhp
            pl.xp = 0
            time.sleep(4)
        else:
            print(bc.blue + "You " + bc.red + "DIED" + bc.blue +
                  "! You are already at the minimum level!\nYou have respawned with your base stats." + bc.end)
            pl.hp = 10
            pl.xp = 0
            time.sleep(4)
    os.remove("mathdata.json")
    pinfo["Level"] = pl.lv
    pinfo["HP"] = pl.hp
    pinfo["HPMax"] = pl.mhp
    pinfo["XP"] = pl.xp
    datas = open("mathdata.json", "w+")
    datas.write(json.dumps(pinfoall + [pinfo]))
    datas.close()


def qmath():
    qv = input(bc.end + "Are you sure you want to quit? (y/n)")
    if qv == "y":
        os.remove("mathdata.json")
        pinfo["Level"] = pl.lv
        pinfo["HP"] = pl.hp
        pinfo["HPMax"] = pl.mhp
        pinfo["XP"] = pl.xp
        datas = open("mathdata.json", "w+")
        datas.write(json.dumps(pinfoall + [pinfo]))
        datas.close()
        print(bc.blue + "\n Thanks for playing, " + bc.green + pl.name + bc.blue + "! See you next time, Math Master!" + bc.end)
        quit()
    elif qv == "n":
        run()
    else:
        print("You must type 'y' or 'n'")
        qmath()


def run():
    cl()
    nums_a_s(pl.lv)
    if pl.lv > 14:
        nums_m_s(pl.lv)
    print(bc.end + "       ------- " + bc.blue + "Player: " + bc.green + pl.name + bc.end + " ------- " + bc.blue +
          "Level: " + bc.green + str(pl.lv) + bc.end + " ------- " + bc.blue + "HP: " + bc.green + str(pl.hp) +
          bc.end + "/" + bc.green + str(pl.mhp) + bc.end + " ------- " + bc.blue + "XP: " + bc.green + str(pl.xp) +
          bc.end + "/" + bc.green + "10" + bc.end + " ------- \n\n")
    print(bc.red + "Here is your question! \n" + bc.end)
    q, a = equation(pl.lv)
    b = input(q)
    if b == "q":
        qmath()
    if str(b) == str(a):
        correct()
    else:
        wrong()
    time.sleep(2)
    run()



run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color in windows are a bit tricky. The shell in pycharm must support color changing ANSI code but cmd of windows doesn't. I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/tartley/colorama

Also, there is this thread that could be useful to you:
[Changing Shell Text Color (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537487/changing-shell-text-color-windows)

Comment: That worked beautifully! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!